# ADF Self hosted integration - how to get this to work when you have a code repository

Tags: azure-data-factory

I set up the integration services self host using the template using the template [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vms-with-selfhost-integration-runtime).  The ADF I have is V2 and is has a code repository.

When I use this template, the integration is added to the adf_publish branch (normally hidden) and not the master stored in VSTS/Git.  This means that none of the connections in the linked services can reference the self hosted integration because it is not visible to that branch.

I have tried setting up a shared link but this does not work for 2 reasons.  The master branch does not have permission to the integration service and the adf_publish integration service cannot grant access to "itself" meaning you cannot select the current data factory as a grant.

Am i doing something wrong or does anyone know a work around?

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug into the RM template that I referenced and it will add the integration runtime (IR) service to the Data Factory mode "branch" and not the collaboration branch (master) which is the root cause.

Bo's answer is correct though the issue was the template - not manual setup of the IR.

The work around was to manually create the IR record in the master branch then create the IR VMs manually and install and authorize the integration gateway on those VMs.  This then propagates to the Data Factory mode and (hopefully) through the CI pipeline.

I have posted a bug to the template repo on GitHub - hopefully they can update it to work with Git hosted collaboration branch (master in our case).

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a self-hosted IR in branch A, the IR will show in branch A (Git mode) and Data Factory mode. You can use the IR in these two mode.
If you want to use it in branch B, you can merge branch A to branch B.

Comment: Thanks - I think my question is more about the template - it appears to adds this directly to the Data Factory mode and I can't see a way of pulling this back onto the master or any other branch.  I could add the IR following the manual steps but wanted to use the template at it was very convenient for covering all the steps,